# Can AppleScript read mouse position / action in one application and replicate it in another application?

Tags: macos, applescript, mouse

I've been searching for a mouse broadcaster for Mac for a while and it seems there are no solutions for doing this, so I must look for alternative solutions now. I'm wondering if AppleScript is capable of performing such a task. Basically, what I would like to do is read mouse position and action when performed in one application for as long as the script is active, and broadcast/replicate it in one or more other applications. Is AppleScript capable of this?

Just to clarify, I'd need to simulate mouse movement in the other applications... for example, if I opened up several instances of a drawing program, assuming that the program had the same resolution, anything I drew in the main program, would replicate on the other programs.

Comment: Mouse movements are rather low-level for AppleScript. You will want to look into `CGEvent`s.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work for what you want, but the NSEvent method, addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:, can send events back to your app from other apps, but I think you would probably only get the location of the mouse on the screen, which, if you don't know the window's location, might not be of much use

Answer (score 1):

Really applescript cannot do what you need. It's not made for that. Applescript is made to run the commands in an application's applescript dictionary. I assume that the dictionary of the applications you want to control give you no way to read and control the mouse.

You do have an applescript alternative though. I have made a command line tool to read the mouse position and also to move the mouse. So theoretically you can do what you want with applescript and my tool. I do not believe you will get the results you expect though. Anyway you can try. Here's a link to the web page for my tool. I hope it helps.
[Get it here.](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html)
Your basic approach could be 1) activate the application you want to read the mouse position, 2) run my tool in a repeat loop and record the mouse positions, 3) activate the second application that you want to duplicate the mouse movements, 4) use a repeat loop with my tool to make the mouse move according to how you recorded it.